# How to get sum of custom attribute values in cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

Some of my products has custom attribute **`pa_ves-g`**. In cart total I need to get entire volume of all products in cart.

I found this code for weight:

```
function myprefix_cart_extra_info() {
    global $woocommerce;
    echo '<div class="cart-extra-info">';
    echo '<p class="total-weight">' . __('Total weight', 'woocommerce');
    echo ' ' . $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_weight . ' ' . 'kg';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

So how to do the same for `pa_ves-g`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are using old (working) cart syntax: you don't need anymore **`global woocommerce;`** if instead using **`$woocommerce->cart`** you use **`WC()->cart`** actual syntax.

Use that code **to get total cart volume** value for **volume** attribute:

```
function myprefix_cart_extra_info() {
    $volume = 0;

    // Iterating though each item in cart
    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    foreach( $cart_items as $cart_item ){
        $item_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $item_id , 'pa_ves-g');
            foreach($terms as $key => $term)
                if(!empty($term->name)) $volume += $term->name;
        }

    echo '<div class="cart-extra-info">';
    echo '<p class="total-weight">' . __('Total volume', 'woocommerce');
    echo ' ' . $volume . ' ' . 'm3';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

*This goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

**This code is tested and works.**

Comment: Thanks for help. But it's not work for me. For debug purposes I added `foreach($cart_item['variation'] as $key => $value)
{
  echo $key." has the value". $value;
}` and here is no volume attribute. It displays only attribute, that I use for make variations. Can you advise?